# Парсинг таблицы с помощью BeautifulSoup4 + lxml

Tags: html, python, css, парсер, beautiful-soup

Есть таблица в которой есть данные. Как получить эти данные, используя `BeautifulSoup` и `lxml`?

[Сам сайт](https://www.net.kg)

Структура таблицы:

```html
<tr class="title"> 
  <td width="5%" height="20" align="center">
   <a href="?cat=&amp;pp=20&amp;old_sort=1&amp;sort=1&amp;orient=desc&amp;sort=1">Позиция</a></td>
  <td width="5%" height="20" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="55%" height="20" align="center">
   <a href="?cat=&amp;pp=20&amp;old_sort=1&amp;sort=1&amp;orient=desc&amp;sort=6">Сайт</a></td>
  <td width="5%" height="20" align="center">
   <a href="?cat=&amp;pp=20&amp;old_sort=1&amp;sort=1&amp;orient=desc&amp;sort=9">KG хиты</a></td>
  <td width="5%" height="20" align="center">
   <a href="?cat=&amp;pp=20&amp;old_sort=1&amp;sort=1&amp;orient=desc&amp;sort=3">Хиты</a></td>
  <td width="5%" height="20" align="center">
   <a href="?cat=&amp;pp=20&amp;old_sort=1&amp;sort=1&amp;orient=desc&amp;sort=4">Посетители</a></td>
  <td width="5%" align="center">    
   <a href="?cat=&amp;pp=20&amp;old_sort=1&amp;sort=1&amp;orient=desc&amp;sort=2">Хосты</a></td>
<!--
  <TD width="5%" align="center">
   <a href="?cat=&pp=20&old_sort=1&sort=1&orient=desc&sort=7"><a href="?cat=&pp=20&old_sort=1&sort=1&orient=desc&sort=7">ТиЦ</a></TD>
  <TD width="5%" align="center">
   <a href="?cat=&pp=20&old_sort=1&sort=1&orient=desc&sort=8"><a href="?cat=&pp=20&old_sort=1&sort=1&orient=desc&sort=8">Pr</a></TD>
//-->
  <td width="5%" height="20" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
```

Нужно получить структурированные данные:

1. Позиций
2. Сайтов
3. Хитов
4. Посетителей
5. Хостов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Накидал простенький парсер](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/a021a741cdf545829844c7c4c886331d571074c4/html_parsing/www_net_kg.py#L25):

- Использование встроенного `html.parser` вместо `lxml`. Для `lxml` заменить на `BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'lxml')`
- Поиск таблицы
- Перебор строк таблицы – `<tr>`
- Перебор ячеек каждой строки таблицы – `<td>`
- Обработка `<td>`
- Сбор результата в список из кортежей

Пример:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_text(tag) -> str:
    if not tag:
        return ''

    return tag.get_text(strip=True)

rs = requests.get('https://www.net.kg/')
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

table = root.select_one('#main_block > table:nth-child(27)')

items = []

for tr in table.select('tr'):
    td_list = tr.select('td')
    if not td_list:
        continue

    pos, _, site, kg_hits, hits, visitors, hosts, _ = td_list
    if not site.a.has_attr('title'):
        continue

    items.append(
        (get_text(pos), site.a['title'], get_text(kg_hits),
         get_text(hits), get_text(visitors), get_text(hosts))
    )

print(items)
# [('1', 'http://mashina.kg', '425065(+17510)', '487000(+21691)', '38624(+1355)', '12222(+140)'),
#  ('2', 'http://diesel.elcat.kg', '343306(-18716)', '362302(-22870)', '28062(-630)', '14393(-439)'),
#  ...
```